# Comparing SQL query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm redesigning some of my database tables. I have 2 keys in the same table that can be used to query data and I'd like to compare the difference in performance between them. Querying with the newer key is slower so I'd like to have a method which I can run after making schema changes to re-assess query performance.

I know about Execution plans in MS SQL Server and `SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON`. However, I'd like to have a very simple absolute time taken which gives me realistic results. Considering each query takes about 4s, I have to run the same query multiple times consecutively in a loop. I currently have:

```
USE [MyDb]

CHECKPOINT
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')

<query>
```

If I ran the above in a loop via powershel `sqlcmd`, would the clearing of the cache be enough to clear effects of running the same query just before the current run?

Comment: If memory serves (someone correct me if I'm wrong) but DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE doesn't clear the the data page buffer pool like DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS, which is what you're really after when you're doing "cold cache" performance testing. Unless you're specifically testing for compile times, I'd stick with DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS.

Comment: [How Stale are my Statistics?](https://littlekendra.com/2009/04/21/how-stale-are-my-statistics/) is just one of a heap of other issues involved in index performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following snippet:

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL')
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```